# Quelles seraient d’autres façons plus jolies et plus claires de dire la phrase citée dans les détails de la question?

Tags: formulation-idiomatique, constructions, formulation, reformulation

Quand nous sortons entre amies et que je suis sa seule amie intime (elle a d’autres amies intimes) ou son amie la plus proche, Véronica cherche à m’en imposer et à me rabaisser devant les autres.

Contexte:

Les autres amies en présence (avec qui nous sommes) sont beaucoup plus proches d’elle que de moi (pour moi elles sont presque des connaissances) et parmi toutes ses amies, je suis celle/celle qui est/son amie?? la plus intime, son amie la plus proche.

---

N’hésitez pas à apporter des modifications à mon texte (phrase en question et contexte) si vous apercevez des fautes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Quand nous sortons entre amies et que je suis sa seule amie intime (elle a d’autres amies intimes) ou son amie la plus proche, Véronica cherche à m’en imposer et à me rabaisser devant les autres.

1. Je suppose que cette phrase inclus plusieurs possibilités, puisqu'elle me semble répétitive.
2. Je pense que l'expression « m'en imposer » est moins usité et plus difficile à comprendre que « me rabaisser ».
3. En français, le mot « intime » est en général réservé pour des discussions en rapport avec le sexe. « Proche » est sûrement plus approprié. La question n'explique pas ce détail.
4. Par rapport au contexte, la phrase originale ne transmet pas l'idée que Véronica connaît mieux « les amies ».

Je simplifierais donc la phrase comme ceci:

> Quand Véronica et moi sortons avec ses amies de longue date et que je suis sa seule amie proche, elle cherche à me rabaisser.

« ses amies [de longue date] » suffit pour comprendre que Véronica les connaît mieux que « moi / je ».